# When printing with Ghostscript, why does -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 give "/undefined in --runpdf--" error after printing PDF?

Tags: ghostscript

I am trying to print a PDF document to a default printer on Windows 10 using Ghostscript 10.02.1. The document prints fine, but each time I get the same error after the PDF file prints. For example, I use the following command:

```
gswin64c -dBATCH -dNOSAFER -dNOPROMPT -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -sOutputFile="%printer%WF-4830" text_graphic_image.pdf
```

The document prints, and I get the following error:

```
Error: /undefined in --runpdf--
Operand stack:   --nostringval--   1   0   --nostringval--   (   **** Error: PDF interpreter encountered an error processing the file.\n)
Execution stack:   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   runpdf   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   runpdf   runpdf   false   1   %stopped_push   1944   1   3   %oparray_pop   1943   1   3   %oparray_pop   1928   1   3   %oparray_pop   1929   1   3   %oparray_pop   runpdf
Dictionary stack:   --dict:755/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:86/200(L)--   --dict:2/10(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: No such file or directoryGPL Ghostscript 10.02.1: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

I have tried the following with the same result:

- multiple PDF documents from different sources
- a printer from a different manufacturer
- installing Ghostscript on a different Windows 10 PC
- earlier versions of Ghostscript: 9.56.0 produces the error while 9.54.0 does not, so I think I am having a problem with the new PDF interpreter implemented in C used in newer Ghostscript versions.

I also added `-dPDFSTOPONERROR` to the command: the documents still print but the error changes:

```
Error: /rangecheck in .installpagedevice
Operand stack:   --nostringval--   1   0   --nostringval--   --dict:96/102(ro)(L)--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false
Execution stack:   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   restore   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   restore   restore   false   1   %stopped_push   1944   1   3   %oparray_pop   1943   1   3   %oparray_pop   1928   1   3   %oparray_pop   1929   1   3   %oparray_pop   restore   restore   1863   4   4   %oparray_pop   restore   1844   4   4   %oparray_pop   restore   restore
Dictionary stack:   --dict:754/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:86/200(L)--   --dict:2/10(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: No such file or directoryGPL Ghostscript 10.02.1: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

I expected to see an error if I tried to just view the document on the display with the following command, but it surprisingly displayed fine and no error occurred:

```
gswin64c -dBATCH -dNOSAFER -dNOPROMPT text_graphic_image.pdf
```

Any help making the documents print error-free would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's a bug I believe, and it's been fixed. You're getting an error restoring the interpreter at the end of the job, which is why the file is printed successfully. You can simply ignore the error.

Comment: Just checked and it works without error on my system using code built from the current HEAD of the Ghostscript Git repository.